# to push id's from clicked divs into my array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

My question is how to push id's from clicked divs into my array , and then compare if the array's length is as long as the other array.Any help would be great!

```
$("#carrot").click (function (){
  bunny.push("#carrot");
})

$("#lettice").click (function (){
  bunny.push ("#lettice");
})

$("#flowers").click (function (){
   bunny.push ("#flowers");
})


var rabbit=["dogs","chickens","chickens"];
var bunny =[];

function store (){ 
if (bunny.length>=rabbit.length){
alert ("yay!");
}}
```

Comment: Just a note on using `ctrl+k` you need to highlight the entire text you wish to turn into code, otherwise it'll appear odd. Also, apart from the fact that you could simply the repetitive clicking functions and odd id saving, what doesn't work with your code? Because it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve your current id by `this.id` OR `$(this).attr("id")` . To compare that you need extra button for checking equal or not .

> You can try by clicking each button and see alert

```js
var rabbit=["dogs","chickens","chickens"];
var bunny =[];

$("#carrot").click (function (){
    bunny.push(this.id);
})

$("#lettice").click (function (){
    bunny.push (this.id);
})

$("#flowers").click (function (){
    bunny.push (this.id);
})

function store (){ 
   if (bunny.length>=rabbit.length){
     alert ("yay!");
   }
   else {
     alert("No");
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="carrot">C</button>
<button id="lettice">L</button>
<button id="flowers">F</button>
<button onclick="store()">Equal</button>
```